# Toggle several divs

Tags: html, hash, toggle

What I would like to do is show a couple of divs out of a selection so that the user get a almost tailor made page the idea is that there are several divs IE:

```
 <div id="vid1">some content</div> 
 <div id="vid2">some content</div>
 <div id="vid3">some content</div>
```

so if the user goes to a page with a name like index.html#vid1 it shows the corresponding div but if they go to the same page but through index.html#vid1&vid3 it shows more than one corresponding divs i don't know if the hash tag is the best way to go about this but i am open to any type of system as long as it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hash with `window.location.hash` and then just split this by the `&` character. Then you have an array containing the div names over which you can iterate. With `document.getElementById()` you can access the according `<div>` and do whatever you want with it

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `display` CSS of the DIV to `none` via JavaScript or similar method.